# Potentially fried raspberry pi

Tags: gpio, boot, rip

I tried to power the raspberry pi though the GPIO pins. I had a 3.7 volt battery charging board that outputed 4.2 volts.

I connected it to 5v and ground on the raspberry pi and the lights were a litle dim so I dicided to connect it to 3.3 volts and ground, thinking it should not make a difference big since the charger is made for 3.7 volt batteries. The lights were now really bright and I heard a high pitched sound.

Now the pi does not boot and the red and green lights are solid

Please help

Edit: I have a raspberry pi 2 
- I probed the GPIO pins snd they are still outputing the correct voltage so maybe ther is still hope.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you did was give a 3.3v chip 4.2 volts - which would definitely fry it.

Answer (score 2):

The Foundation warns "Under no circumstances should a power source be connected to the 3.3V pins."

Even if this did not fry the 3.3V regulator, this would result in the SOC being powered in the wrong sequence, with potentially damaging consequences.

Comment: So... Is there any fix or is getting the new rpi3 b+ a better option?

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying you connected power to pin 1 of the Pi (3V3) and a Pi ground pin then you have likely destroyed the Pi.  There is nothing to be done.

**ONLY** power the Pi via a 5V pin (2 or 4) and a Pi ground pin if you want to power via the expansion header.

Comment: Doesn't the rpi2 have GPIO protection?

Comment: @Batleram , What do you mean by GPIO protection??? Also, you said "I probed the GPIO pins and they are still outputting the correct voltage so maybe there's still hope". Unfortunately, there most likely is not - the voltage outputted to the GPIO power pins is controlled by voltage regulators: chips that are much heavier duty and durable than the main processor. Just because the voltage regulators _aren't_ fried doesn't mean the main chip isn't.

Comment: what does GPIO protection have to do with connecting to a 3v3 pin? 5v/3v3/Gnd are not GPIO's